# Activity indicator not animating when creating a dispatch group in iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to display an activity indicator while performing some network calls in a `dispatch_group_asyc` block. But activity indicator only shows when the block finishes. I'm creating a `dispatch_group_t` because I need to get the result of the network calls before performing some other tasks. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
- (BOOL)doNetCall
{
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];

  __block BOOL netResult = NO;

  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(netQueue, NULL);
  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
  dispatch_group_async(group,queue,^{
    netResult = [service queryService];
  });

  dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  dispatch_release(group);
  dispatch_release(queue);

  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

  if (netResult) {  
    // Perform some tasks
  }
  else {
    [self showAlertView];
  }

  return netResult;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I need the method to wait until the block finishes in order to return the result I get

Comment: You are blocking the main thread with the call to `dispatch_group_wait`. This is very bad. Do not do what you are doing on the main thread.

Comment: Why are you using a dispatch group for this?

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, my fault, this code is in a method that should return a value when the async task completed. I edited my question

Answer (score 4):

You should use activity indicator in this way:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

If you're using `group`, just rewrite your code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any need for a dispatch group with what you are doing. Try this:

```
- (void)buttonClicked {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        BOOL netResult = [service queryService];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

            if (netResult) {
                // perform some tasks
            } else {
                // show alert
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If you have your queue, replace the call to `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` with your own queue.